# Looping through DF column to remove rows that have spanish text

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here is the code I'm using to filter out any spanish text:

```
from langdetect import detect  #detects what language is written
from  tqdm import tqdm #timing package

# 'summary_processed' is a list of sentence strings that had general text preprocessing done (lemmetization, regex removal, lowercasing, etc)
summary_processed_en = [i for i in tqdm(summary_processed) if detect(i) == 'en']
```

Now, this isn't a typical conditional statement so I can't do my normal `df[df == "X"]` format.

I'm not entire sure how to approach this. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is `tqdm`? What is `summary_processed`? What is `detect`?

Comment: Added more detail

Comment: hey @madsthaks, this seems to work on my machine (ie `summary_process_en` produces only the english results). Is there something else you're looking for? Do you want `summary_process_en` to be added to a df somewhere?

Comment: This line does work but what I want to do is filter an entire dataframe based on this condition.

Comment: @madsthaks a little more detail on your df would be great -- what are the relevant column names etc!

Answer (score 1):

You can use apply and a lambda to do this pretty easily.

```
index = df['a'].apply(lambda x: detect(x) == 'en')
```

then you can apply the index to whatever column you want. Alternatively you can just do

```
df['a'] == df['a'].apply(lambda x: detect(x) == 'en')
```

to do it on the same column.

Comment: So, would this be the properly syntax: `df[df['a'] == df['a'].apply(lambda x: detect(x) == 'en')]`? When I do this, I get an empty dataframe